# Logging not working for PostgreSQL 14 on Windows

Tags: postgresql, logging

I have edited the postgresql.conf file and set logging parameters as follows. However, after I restart and look a the logging_collector value, it's set to off and logging is not working:

```
log_destination = 'csvlog'
logging_collector = on
log_directory = 'log'
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d.log'
log_rotation_age = 1d
log_rotation_size = 100MB
log_truncate_on_rotation = on

select * from pg_settings where name like 'log%'
"log_autovacuum_min_duration"   "-1"
"log_checkpoints"   "off"
"log_connections"   "on"
"log_destination"   "csvlog"
"log_directory" "log"
"log_disconnections"    "off"
"log_duration"  "off"
"log_error_verbosity"   "default"
"log_executor_stats"    "off"
"log_file_mode" "0640"
"log_filename"  "postgresql-%Y-%m-%d.log"
"log_hostname"  "off"
"log_line_prefix"   "%m [%p] "
"log_lock_waits"    "off"
"log_min_duration_sample"   "-1"
"log_min_duration_statement"    "-1"
"log_min_error_statement"   "error"
"log_min_messages"  "warning"
"log_parameter_max_length"  "-1"
"log_parameter_max_length_on_error" "0"
"log_parser_stats"  "off"
"log_planner_stats" "off"
"log_recovery_conflict_waits"   "off"
"log_replication_commands"  "off"
"log_rotation_age"  "1440"
"log_rotation_size" "102400"
"log_statement" "none"
"log_statement_sample_rate" "1"
"log_statement_stats"   "off"
"log_temp_files"    "-1"
"log_timezone"  "America/Chicago"
"log_transaction_sample_rate"   "0"
"log_truncate_on_rotation"  "on"
**"logging_collector"   "off"**
"logical_decoding_work_mem" "65536"
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you edited the wrong file, or you restarted the wrong server, or the setting is overridden somewhere else. You got the right idea by looking at `pg_settings`, but you looked at the wrong columns:

```
SELECT setting, source, sourcefile, sourceline, pending_restart
FROM pg_settings
WHERE name = 'logging_collector';
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot, there was a line lower in my config file that turned it off, so you were definitely correct. My mistake, thanks!